# Zend Navigation with Smarty

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty, zend-navigation

I want to create breadscrumb in Smarty template using Zend_Navigation.

So far what I did:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml');
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
```

How do I use $navigation in the template?

Usualy in the layout navigation

```
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setLinkLast(false)->setMinDepth(0)->render();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$smarty->assign('breadcrumbs', $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setLinkLast(false)->setMinDepth(0)->render());
```

and then use

```
$breadcrumbs
```

in your smarty template